# WebStorm underlines variables and functions in red despite my Angular2 TypeScript project works correctly

Tags: intellij-idea, angular, typescript, webstorm

When I open the project in WebStorm everything looks fine. Whenever I double click any of the .ts files it's being immediately marked red indicating a problem. Despite this, project works normally, the code is being executed correctly etc.

For a reference, this is not a project specific problem, because a friend of mine working with exactly the same code, has no errors indicated by IDE.

For example, let's take  this repo https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter. When browsing the project, I get the errors like

> Unresolved variable data

[image]

> Unresolved function or method require()

[image]

I also have an error with @Component annotation everywhere it's present in the project with `Invalid number of arguments, expected 0`:
[image]

I have npm version 3.9.5, node version 6.2.2 and WebStorm version 2016.2.1 . I did `npm install` and `bower install`.

Comment: My Webstorm is always telling me stuff is wrong when it's not with Angular2.  Try updating Webstorm (I think there's a minor fix just been released).  Might also be worth checking the 'typings' are up to date.

Comment: the bug should be fixed in WS 2016.2.2

Comment: @anstarovoyt are you sure my problem is related? Can you give me some reference to source?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22697

Comment: @anstarovoyt Thanks! I updated to version 2016.2.2 and now it works.

Comment: I am on 2016.2.2 and I have `myArray.find()` and `Object.assign()` in red too. How can it be fixed ? (In an angular2 app)